# Infinite Scroll plugin on Ebuy theme

Tags: plugins

So Ebuy does not support infinite scroll, and my coding knowledge is minimal. I'm looking for some guidance as to how i can manually get in there and make infinite scroll work. Ive already got the plug in activated, but i am unsure as to what to put in the content selector, nav selector, next selector, item selector, and call back fields.

http://soballer.com/product/accessories/

thats what it looks like now. it shows 10 items, then you have to click on "older entries". if anyone could help me set this up, id appreciate it! thanks

Comment: Please add a link to the plugin’s source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page that you have mentioned above has the following markup

```
<div id="content">
<div class="box " id="post-302"></div>
<div class="box " id="post-298"></div>  
<div class="box lastbox" id="post-296"></div>   
<div class="box " id="post-293"></div>      
<div class="box " id="post-265"></div>
<div class="box lastbox" id="post-259">

        <div id="navigation">
        <div class="alignleft"><a href="http://soballer.com/product/accessories/page/2/">« Older Entries</a></div>
        <div class="alignright"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Try these:

```
content selector -- #content
nav selector -- .alignleft
next selector -- .alignleft a
item selector -- .box
```

Comment: awesome man, made some progress. now all i have to do is line it up correctly. its still a little out of wack. you can see what i mean if you click the link in my OP.                               -also, toscho i dont know how to find the source code of this plugin

Comment: also shubhra can you tell me how you found that code and how you knew to use box and alignleft... im new and tryin to learn some stuff. thanks